# open(create) non existing file in lua

Tags: file, printing, lua, arguments

I'm trying to save a configtable(parsed to string) to a file wich is created just in time.

```
local cfg_string = table.tostring(cfg_table)
local file_name = ""
local cfg_file = ""

file_name = com:line(nil)    -- reads a line of input from user via terminal
file_name = string.format("some_prefix-%s-some_suffix.lua",file_name)
-- file does NOT exist at this line

cfg_file = io.open("/dir/subdir/"..file_name,"w")
-- file now should exist

os.syslog(type(file_name)) -> string
os.syslog(type(cfg_file)) -> nil
os.syslog(type(cfg_string)) -> string
cfg_file:write(cfg_string)
```

cfg_file:write(cfg_string) throws "attempt to call "write" a nil value".
So hu,.. cfg_file is nil I know, but why? I also tried to io.open() with "a" flag, but this doesn't work too. The directory exists!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `cfg_file, err = io.open("/dir/subdir/"..file_name,"w")` and `print(err)` check out what the error is.

Comment: I had no permission to write to the dir. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, my code is working. The error is thrown because missig write-permission to dir.

Everyone with such Errors should try

```
handle_name, err = io.open(file,"w")
print(err)
```

Comment: Use `handle_name = assert(io.open(file,"w"))` if you want to abort if the open fails.